# I get a "Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined" when debugging within Android, but not under the Chrome Debugger

Tags: javascript, android, debugging, cordova, sencha-touch

I've been tasked with upgrading a Phonegap + Sencha projecto from Phonegap 1.2.0 to 2.1.0 and to Sencha 2 and I've been doing the blunt of the job debugging under Chrome+jetty, where iterations between modifications are faster.

After struggling a bit with the migration part, I got to a point where the project launches on Chrome (i.e: I can execute my launch method on the debugger, and the application loads), but when I try the same thing on Android I get the **Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined**.

The HTML file called in android looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing ExtJS 4</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/sencha/resources/css/android_v01.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/hx/resources/css/prosegur.css" type="text/css">

        <!-- libs -->
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="libs/phonegap/cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/sencha/sencha-touch-all-compat.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery/xml2json.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/aes/aes.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            currentPlatform="Android";
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/App.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

db_name="PMobileDB";
db_version="1.0";
DEBUG_MODE=false;
LOG_FILE="sdcard/xlogx.txt";

function fireCreateLocalStore() {   
 var prosegurConfig = window.localStorage.getItem('ProsegurConfig');
 if (prosegurConfig == null) {
    prosegurConfig = new Object();
    prosegurConfig.configuration = {
        esClienteProsegur: false,
        estaActivadoClienteProsegur: false,
        nroContrato: '',
        paisDeContrato: 'ARG',
        paisDeResidencia: 'ARG',
        nombre: '',
        cel: '',
        fechaNacimiento: '',
        email: '',
        estado: 'NO_CONFIGURADO',
        wsMobileConfig: 'https://psm.am:1962/wsProseguardConfig.asmx/wsMobileConfig',
        wsHashActivation: 'https://psm.am:1962/wsProseguardConfig.asmx/wsHashActivation',
        wsAlertFire: 'https://psm.am:1962/wsProseguardAlerts.asmx/wsAlertFire',
        guardianPin: '',
        startGuardianAlertTime: '',
        version: db_version
    };
    prosegurConfig.alerts = [
        { 
            alertType: 'GENERAL',
            description: '', 
            tryContactCRA: false
        },
        {
            alertType: 'MEDICAL',
            description: '',
            tryContactCRA: false
        },
        {
            alertType: 'CARASSISTANCE',
            description: '',
            tryContactCRA: false
        }
    ];
    prosegurConfig.contacts = new Array();
    window.localStorage.setItem('ProsegurConfig', Ext.JSON.encode(prosegurConfig));
    console.log('se carga los datos iniciales de Prosegur');
 }
 console.log(prosegurConfig);
 console.log('arranco app.mainLaunch()');
 app.app.launch();
 console.log('salgo de app.mainLaunch');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">document.addEventListener("deviceready", fireCreateLocalStore,false);
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

First, I know that **app** is a poor choice for the global object, I think that particular thing changed between 1.4.0 and 1.5.0, so, whilst the original call to the launch() method was like:

app.launch();

I found out that that wouldn't work in 2.1.0 and that I could call it like:

app.app.launch();

This works allright in Chrome where calling fireCreateLocalStore() from the code I pasted above ends calling it.

Now, when I compile this in Eclipse and deploy it with the debug option, I see the logcat going through the creation of the database objects (just before) and when it hits the launch() line I get the error from the title : Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined

I tried changing the offending global to something less conflicting, like MyApp in the html and App.js (plus the default view) to no avail, thus now, I'm kind of stuck with this.

By the way, my App.js looks like this:

```
// Main application entry point
Ext.application({
name: 'app',
phoneStartupScreen: '../resources/images/LOADING_01.png',
tabletStartupScreen: '../resources/images/LOADING_01.png',
glossOnIcon: true,
    fullscreen: true,
autoCreateViewport : true,

// the controller will take care of creating the view        
//controllers: ['Configuration', 'ImmediateAlert', 'Guardian', 'Log'],
controllers: ['Configuration', 'ImmediateAlert', 'Guardian'],

// You could delete this, here only to illustrate
   // the sequence of events        
initialize: function () {
    console.log('app initialize');
    this.callParent();
},

launch: function() {
    console.log(app);
    this.launched = true;
    Ext.create("app.view.Viewport");
    this.mainLaunch();
},
mainLaunch: function() {
    //if (!device || !this.launched) {return;}
    if (!this.launched) {return;}
    console.log('MainLaunch : loading in ' + currentPlatform );

    Ext.getCmp('navigationView').getNavigationBar().add({id: 'save',
        text: 'Guardar',
        ui: 'light',
        align: 'right',
   })

   if (app.store == undefined)
        app.store = new Object();

   app.store.contacts = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
       model: "app.model.Contact"
   });

   app.store.alerts = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'app.model.Alert',
   });

   app.service.ProsegurLocalStorageStore.populateStores(app.store.alerts);

   app.service.ProsegurLocalStorageStore.populateContactStores(app.store.contacts);

   var config = app.service.ProsegurLocalStorageStore.getConfiguration();
            console.log('ATENCION' + app.configuration.GeneralConfiguration.fireAlertService());
   if (config.data.wsBaseURL != null && config.data.wsBaseURL != '') {
        app.configuration.GeneralConfiguration.prosegurServiceBaseURL = config.data.wsBaseURL;
    }
    if (config.data.wsBaseCriticalURL != null && config.data.wsBaseCriticalURL != '') {
        app.configuration.GeneralConfiguration.prosegurServiceCriticalBaseURL = config.data.wsBaseCriticalURL;
    }

   if (currentPlatform == "MacOS"){ 
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
    }


   Ext.MessageBox.YESNO=[{itemId:'no',text:'NO'},{itemId:'yes',text:'Si'}];
   Ext.MessageBox.OK = {itemId:'ok',text:'Aceptar'};
   Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL=[{itemId:'cancel',text:'Cancelar'},{itemId:'ok',text:'Aceptar'}];



   Ext.Date.dayNames = [
                        'Domingo',
                        'Lunes',
                        'Martes',
                        'Miercoles',
                        'Jueves',
                        'Viernes',
                        'Sabado'
                    ];

                    Ext.Date.monthNames = [
                        'Enero',
                        'Febrero',
                        'Marzo',
                        'Abril',
                        'Mayo',
                        'Junio',
                        'Julio',
                        'Agosto',
                        'Septiembre',
                        'Octubre',
                        'Noviembre',
                        'Diciembre'
                    ];

                    Ext.Date.monthNumbers = {
                        'Ene': 0,
                        'Feb': 1,
                        'Mar': 2,
                        'Abr': 3,
                        'May': 4,
                        'Jun': 5,
                        'Jul': 6,
                        'Ago': 7,
                        'Sep': 8,
                        'Oct': 9,
                        'Nov': 10,
                        'Dic': 11
                    };

                    if (Ext.is.Android) {
                          Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(function() {
                            Ext.Viewport.scrollToTop();
                            Ext.Viewport.updateBodySize();
                            Ext.Viewport.fireEvent('resize', Ext.Viewport, Ext.getBody().getSize());
                            app.views.viewport.getActiveItem().fireEvent('resize');
                          });
                    };

                    app.service.ProsegurServiceCallbackDaemon.run();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is more than likely that "app" is conflicting with "navigator.app" which is a PhoneGap API. If you can change the name of your Sencha application it would probably be your best bet.

Comment: Well, I've tried changing those references from app to MyApp in App.js , View and index-android.html do you think I might be missing something else?